# how to choose more than one dimension using principle component analysis

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

i recently read PCA (Principle Component Analysis) and understood that how to reduce dimension. we select an eigenvector corresponding to maximum eigenvalue when we need only one dimension but if need more than one dimension then should i take  eigenvectors corrosponding to maximum eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

Principal component analysis (PCA) is a statistical technique that carries out an orthogonal transformation to convert a set of observations of possibly correlated variables into a set of values of linearly uncorrelated variables called principal components.

The number of components after PCA transformation is equal to the number of variables. This transformation is defined in such a way that the first principal component has the largest possible variance (that is, it accounts for as much of the variability in the data as possible), and each succeeding component in turn has the highest variance possible under the constraint that it is orthogonal to the preceding components. The resulting vectors are an uncorrelated orthogonal basis set.

Generally, people take as many components that accounts for 99% variance, which will be much lesser than the total number of variables.

*References:*

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140579/86202

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#pca

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes(from what can be infered from your description), it would be nice to have more information in your case, your implementation tool ,etc. But basically yes , the process would be:

1. Compute covariance matrix
2. Compute eigenvectors of the covariance matrix,depending on your tool it can be computed using pre-defined functions "eig" or also "singular value descomposition" (svd in matlab). If you use svd, it commonly will return 3 values, the first value its a matrix wich will contain the eigenvectors , of this matrix if you want "k" dimensions , you take "k" columns and they are your principal components.

Heres my implementation in octave of PCA, i use a pca.m file  to define my pca calculation and ex7_pca.m to use it for dimensinality reduction for that particular case:
https://github.com/llealgt/standord_machine_learning_exercices/blob/master/machine-learning-ex7/ex7/pca.m

https://github.com/llealgt/standord_machine_learning_exercices/blob/master/machine-learning-ex7/ex7/ex7_pca.m